# Subgroups of $Z^n$ are finitely generated

Tags: abelian-groups, finitely-generated

I have read a couple of proofs already, but all of them try to go further and start talking about modules. Is there any more direct proof of this fact without using modules?

Comment: Hint: all subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ has the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Maybe this helps.

Comment: I thought about starting by induction, that would be the first step. But I really don't know how to continue.

Comment: In each of the proofs you read, substitute "abelian group" for "module", and you'll be well on your way to having a direct proof.

Comment: What I meant if the proof can get easier (more direct) if we restrict to abelian groups

Comment: You looked for $\mathbb{Z}^{n}\simeq(\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Yes, but my problem is, does that mean that a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is of the form $H_{n-1}\times H$ where $H_{n-1}<\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$ and $H<\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Got it. I do not know.

Comment: @Smurf: no, that's incorrect. For the correct statement see Goursat's lemma.

Comment: It looks like Goursat's Lemma only says something about some specific subgroups, those whose projections are surjective. How to do it for every subgroup?

Comment: I don't know if this way can lead to something: if you try to do it by induction, $H<\mathbb{Z}^n$, and you consider the projections $f_i:\mathbb{Z}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, becomes aparent that $\ker(f_i|_{H})<\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, so all of those kernels are finitely generated by induction, any ideas on how to continue?

Comment: Alright I think I got it, check my answer please

Comment: @Smurf: the projections are surjective without loss of generality. You just restrict your attention to the product of the image of the projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's proceed by induction over $n$, if $n=1$ we have that $H=k\mathbb{Z}$ so it is obviously free.

Let assume the result holds for every $0<i<n+1$, and let $H<\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}=\langle e_1,\cdots,e_{n+1}\rangle$, consider the projection
$$\begin{matrix}f:\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{Z}\\k=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}m_ie_i&\longmapsto&m_1e_1\end{matrix}$$
then we have the following short exact secuence
$$\ker f|_H\longrightarrow H\longrightarrow f(H)$$
since $f(B)<\mathbb{Z}$ it must be ciclic (so it is free), therefor
$$H\cong \ker f|_H\oplus f(B)$$
and $\ker f|_H<\langle e_2,\cdots,e_{n+1}\rangle=\mathbb{R}^n$ so, by induction, it is free so $H$ must be free too.

P.D. I change "finitely generated" for "free", since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is free of torsion both are the same.